# Xcode no longer opens up assistant editors when I option-click

Tags: ios, xcode

This is pretty frustrating. Last week, without updating or changing any settings, if I option-click on a file in the sidebar or in search, it will no longer open that file in a new assistant editor to the right of my current file.

I also can't cmd-option-control-T to open up an assistant editor either.

I just updated to Xcode 12.5.1, I restarted, no luck.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Edit: Other projects in Xcode show assistant editor, it's just this one project.

Comment: In my case it was Focus button. Press Shift + control + command + enter to disable Focus mode.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Solved by following these steps

1. **Clean the Build**: Menu Bar → Product → Clean
2. **Clean the Build Folder**: Menu Bar → Product → Hold Option Key → Clean build Folder
3. **Delete Xcode Preferences**: Run in terminal, `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`

**Last Resort**: Run [XCode fix script by Mark Rickert](https://gist.github.com/vineetchoudhary/b09c3f40ca29d36c8863#file-fix-xcode-rb)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @minchaej. No luck running steps 1-3 and restarting Xcode unfortunately. Looking into Mark Rickert's script now

Comment: Xcode has become very buggy recently for me as well :(

Comment: It's strange because it's only one project. Other projects behave fine and I didn't update any settings to trigger this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @minchaelj, see the accepted answer, if you're curious

Comment: @ZackShapiro Woah thanks as well!